# Are there any Rishonim buried in England and France

Tags: rabbis, historical-figures, rishonim, cemetery-grave

Do we know of any of the burial places of Rishonim around France and England? I know Rabbi Yisrael Meir Gabbai has found some but are there any tools to source ancient Jewish cemeteries e.g. a map?

Comment: Start here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi#Death_and_burial_site

Comment: Is this on-topic?

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that there are any Rishonim buried in England, if there is there are not many. Many Rishonim are buried in France though.
- Rashi
- Rabbeinu Tam
- Rashbam
- Ri
- The Radak
many others.

Comment: The Ri meorleans was murdered in London, so likely buried in a graveyard in the UK. Unfortunately unknown. R'yom tov mi joingy was murdered in York; although we do know where the York cemetery is it apparently the victims of that massacre were not buried there

Comment: Not the Ri meorleans, I am talking about Ri HaZaken, Rashi's son.

Comment: I know. Just pointing out that there are well-known rishomim buried in the uk

Comment: @AvrohomKanievsky Rashi had no sons

Comment: Sorry I meant his grandson.

Comment: I assume the Ba'al Tosafot Anglia is buried there (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosafot_Hachmei_Anglia)