# Known tombs/graves of Rishonim in Europe

Tags: rishonim, cemetery-grave

Are there any graves of Rishonim that are known in Europe (not a whole cemetery like in Worms but the actual tomb)?

I know about the Maharal and Rema as well as the oldest known from a rabbi  (that of Rabbi Avigdor Kara; dates from 1439) but are there any of more well-known Rishonim?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105795/are-there-any-rishonim-buried-in-england-and-france

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say - "not a whole cemetery like in Worms but the actual tomb" because the Heiliger Sand cemetary in Worms has the Maharam MiRottenburg buried there. Does that qualify?

Answer (score 1):

The [Raavad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_David)'s kever is located [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ancien+cimeti%C3%A8re+juif+m%C3%A9di%C3%A9val,+s%C3%A9pultures+des+Kabbalistes+Abraham+ben+David+le+Rabad+III+et+son+fils+Isaac+l%27Aveugle/@43.6894793,4.281771,18z/data=!4m14!1m7!3m6!1s0x12b6825dc62c3e3b:0xe06bcf66cf43a070!2sFondation+Partage+et+Vie+-+EHPAD+L%27Accueil+-+Vauvert!8m2!3d43.6899702!4d4.2806447!16s%2Fg%2F1tdtykrf!3m5!1s0x12b683cc4588e919:0x8128fed5add96698!8m2!3d43.6894039!4d4.2814724!16s%2Fg%2F11sfrb1_zj?entry=ttu) in the French town called Vauvert (formely known as Posquières) - Rabbi Daniel Glatstein visited it [here](https://beta.torahanytime.com/lectures/200087?_noscroll=1&action=watch)

Comment: From R. Glatstein's video it seems like this is a newish tombstone and there are no other tombstones around there and the cemetery was destroyed over the years like many others in Europe.  Is it known how the exact spot of the Raavad's kever was identified and who put the new stone there?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can see a [photo of the grave](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:J%C3%BCdischer_Friedhof_Worms-4243.jpg) of the [Maharil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin) in the old Jewish cemetery of Worms *(known as the Heiliger Sand)*.

More on that grave [here](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=29983) and [here](https://www.zadikim.net/?p=886).

The grave of the [author of the Rokeach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) is also in that cemetery *(in addition to the Maharam MiRottenburg mentioned in Dov's earlier comment)*.  However I'm not sure whether someone has identified the exact location and whether the original tombstone still exists there.